# Foldl on string

Tags: haskell, fold

I would like to foldl a string so that any occurrence of zero which is preceded by @ is replaced with "k". So "a.@0.1.2.0" becomes, "a.@k.1.2.0". How do I do that? So far my attempt is

```
test = foldl(\x acc-> if((last acc) == "@" && x == "0" then acc ++ "k" else acc ++ x)) "" "a.@0.1.2.0"
```

However, it doesn't work. Foldl is expecting list of string and what I'm providing is just a string. How do I overcome that?

Comment: Don't do this with `foldl`. This is definitely a `foldr` or `mapAccumL` problem. `foldl` will surely make this slow.

Comment: But how do I know if given 0 is preceded by @ if I use foldr.

Comment: Why use any fold at all?

Comment: Yeah, `mapAccumL`, which for lists is a fold, is probably the easiest way. `foldr` can do it, but it's a little tricky to see how.

Comment: There is a whole string library at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hS3-0.5.8/docs/Data-String-Utils.html

Comment: I prefer to stay within prelude if possible.

Comment: Well, staying within the prelude, you should surely use `zipWith`. Extending to standard libraries, `mapAccumL` in `Data.List` is attractive. `foldr` is definitely doable, but it's a somewhat more advanced technique. `foldl` just seems silly here.

Comment: I'd use explicit recursion and pattern matching. Do you really need to use folds?

Comment: @chi's suggestion is probably the best way to start, to give you a better feel for the problem, even if you eventually want to do it some other way.

Comment: As for your attempt, one thing I notice is that you are comparing characters (e.g. `last acc` and `x`) to strings (`"@"` and `"0"`).  You should compare them to characters `'@'` and `'0'` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking chi's advice,

```
rep "" = ""
rep ('@' : '0' : xs) = "@k" ++ rep xs
rep (x : xs) = x : rep xs
```

If we want to get fancier,

```
rep = snd . mapAccumL go False
  where
    go True '0' = (False, 'k')
    go _ '@' = (True, '@')
    go _ x = (False, x)
```

or even

```
rep = snd . mapAccumL go 'x'
  where
    go '@' '0' = ('0', 'k')
    go _ y = (y, y)
```

To use `foldr` with this second approach (just because it's shorter; the first will work fine too, and allows generalization),

```
rep xs = foldr go (const "") xs 'x'
  where
    go '0' r '@' = 'k' : r '0'
    go x r _ = x : r x
```

To use `zipWith` (which is more awkward to generalize):

```
rep xs = zipWith go ('x' : xs) xs where
  go '@' '0' = 'k'
  go _ x = x
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, `foldl` would *not* fit well for this task. However, using the idea of [difference list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list), you may still do this *efficiently* using `foldl`:

```
repl :: String -> String
repl a = foldl loop id a ""
    where
    loop :: (String -> String) -> Char -> (String -> String)
    loop f '@' ('0':rest) = f ('@':'k':rest)
    loop f x xs = f (x:xs)
```

Just for the purpose of demonstration and the fact that the question has asked for a `foldl` solution. (not that I would recommend doing it this way).

Comment: While this should have the right asymptotic bounds, much like the "build backwards, then reverse" technique, it is entirely strict in the spine of the list and therefore inefficient in practice.